# Is there any Scriptural proof of Ruju Ganas,Jeeva Jeeva Bheda,Svarupa Jnana etc concepts propounded by Shri Madhvacharya ji?

Tags: vedanta, dvaita, reference-request, madhvacharya

Is there any Scriptural proof of Ruju Ganas, Jeeva Jeeva Bheda, Svarupa Jnana, etc. concepts propounded by Shri Madhvacharya ji?

Kindly quote scriptural references

Thank You

Comment: Jeeva Jeeva bheda is practical and obvious its like asking give me scriptual proof the differences we see in this world.  Svarupa Jana BG 15.7

Answer (score 3):

in the Taittiriya Upanishad (2.7), it is mentioned, "**Atmanam viddhi, shariram viddhi, vidyam cha avidyam cha**" which means

> "Know the Self, know the body, know both knowledge and ignorance". This implies that there is a distinction between the individual soul (Jiva) and the body, as well as the knowledge and ignorance that influence the soul's actions.

Similarly, in the Bhagavad Gita (13.2), Lord Krishna says,

> "This body, O son of Kunti, is called the field, and he who knows it is called the knower of the field." Here, Lord Krishna is indicating that there is a difference between the body (field) and the soul (knower of the field).

In the Srimad Bhagavatam (1.2.10), it is stated,

> "Learned circles have positively concluded that the infallible purpose of the advancement of knowledge, namely austerities, study of the Vedas, sacrifice, chanting of hymns and charity culminates in the transcendental descriptions of the Lord, who is defined in choice poetry." This verse supports the concept of Svarupa Jnana, which refers to the knowledge of the true nature of the soul and its relationship with the Supreme Personality of Godhead.